# What does "too localized" really entail?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, voting

Having just received the ability to vote-to-close questions I have seen the option of "Too localized".

At what point is the question deemed to be too localized?  I personally have asked questions that are specific to my needs and conditions.  The answers could in some ways help a few down the road, but not the general public.

Here's an example: [System critical error "Kernel Power" and crash](https://superuser.com/questions/184868/system-critical-error-kernel-power-and-crash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the description states, it is a question that has too narrow a focus. For example, asking what the best Service Provider is in the UK, or asking about a particular product which is specific to a certain company and not well known.

This is not often used, and when it does moderators normally intervene to ensure it is used for the correct purpose. There is enough cases where it is the only close reason that make sense and therefore it was added to the list.

Comment: Oh ok that makes more sense... Thanks.