# Take away the chinese tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

While working on [Manufacturer & Company tags are back. Again](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8402/393570) I have come across the tag [chinese](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chinese). There are quite a few questions on there of varying quality.

What is it for, why do we have tags specifically for human languages?

Similarly I have found the following language tags:

- [spanish](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/spanish)
- [german](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/german)
- [english](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/english)
- [japanese](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/japanese)

Would these be better served being retagged as [localization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/localization)? It is quite possible that I have missed the point of these tags.

Comment: For a minute, I thought this post was written by Donald Trump.  The only reason I could see for something other than localization would be if languages based on non-Latin characters have implications beyond locale settings and language packs.  But even then, everything falling into that category should have a single tag, not language-specific tags.

Comment: There is also already a https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding tag which may cover a lot of these questions

Comment: @fixer1234 you can blame JMG for the title: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31759433#31759433

Comment: `latin1` is an encoding though, not a language. :D

Comment: @DanielB thanks! I have removed it from my list.

Comment: Is this question's title adhering to the entrenched standard of making a pun when talking about removing the tag?  Ideas: Great Walling off [china] ...

Comment: Re: "I thought this post was written by Donald Trump"  I assume this post was written by a Clinton supporter. Really? Why do politics have to enter into these discussions? That post is inappropriate as is this one.

Comment: @tgunr I think he was joking

Comment: @TOOGAM Yes it is, but you're not catching it. I think it's hilarious.

Comment: @TOOGAM Are you sure he didn't carry out the pun?

Comment: @Hydranix : All I was able to recognize appeared to be a racial slur (indicating Chinese people aren't wanted).  However I felt unsure of any such thing (to bluntly answer your question), so I took the civil route of simply asking an innocent question. It seems there is more to this than I recognized.  Some Google searching indicates some people may use "take away" to refer to Chinese food which I would say is "to go", or "carry out", or maybe "take out".  I'm still not sure I got that right, but as an intentional non-partaker of Chinese restaurants, I can be content to just not worry about it

Comment: Unbelievable the attention the title has received.  Hopefully, it did its job of attracting viewers to get actual input on the issue.  @tgunr, just to answer your question, Trump is always talking about fixing the trade imbalance the US has with China.  China is one of his hot button issues that he mentions all the time.  Hence, the observation that the title looked like something he might have written.  And yes, it was a joke, not politics.

Comment: I suggested the title - [takeout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Take-out) seems to be an Americanism and a thrope in media [There's even a movies question on it](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17641/what-is-the-symbolism-of-eating-chinese-take-out-in-a-scene). I'm actually baffled to how it could be seen as racist. I suppose nothing seperates us like the language, even if I've personally used three of the other varients, takeaway, parcel and "tah pao" in singapore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are languages too localized?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3553/are-languages-too-localized)

Answer (score 7):

As I understand it, many language-related issues are specific to the language. Tags for the individual languages are more likely to get the right people to see these questions. This seems useful and perfectly reasonable to me.

Instead of burning these tags, I suggest that we edit the tag wiki excerpts to specify proper usage. E.g.,

> Use this tag for issues specific to the Chinese language. This tag
>   should be used in coordination with another tag for the nature of the
>   issue, e.g., [input-languages], [ime], or [character-encoding].

There are lots of suggested tags that could potentially be listed in the excerpt. From what I've seen, there's a fair bit of overlap in these tags. I'm not an expert on any of these topics, so people who actually know this stuff should decide which ones to suggest. Here are some I spotted just going through the questions tagged [chinese](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/chinese):

[input-languages](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/input-languages)
[language](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/language)
[character-encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding)
[unicode](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unicode)
[keyboard-layout](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/keyboard-layout)
[ime](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ime)
[localization](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/localization)

Comment: That is a good idea. Can we force it so if someone chooses a language they HAVE to select one of the tags you have mentioned?

Comment: @Burgi No, there's no way to require that. It's falls on editors to notice these things and fix them as they appear.